# Gaussian fit for Python

Tags: python, gaussian

I'm trying to fit a Gaussian for my data (which is already a rough gaussian). I've already taken the advice of those here and tried `curve_fit` and `leastsq` but I think that I'm missing something more fundamental (in that I have no idea how to use the command). 
Here's a look at the script I have so far

```
import pylab as plb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read in data -- first 2 rows are header in this example. 
data = plb.loadtxt('part 2.csv', skiprows=2, delimiter=',')

x = data[:,2]
y = data[:,3]
mean = sum(x*y)
sigma = sum(y*(x - mean)**2)

def gauss_function(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(gauss_function, x, y, p0 = [1, mean, sigma])
plt.plot(x, gauss_function(x, *popt), label='fit')

# plot data

plt.plot(x, y,'b')

# Add some axis labels

plt.legend()
plt.title('Fig. 3 - Fit for Time Constant')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.show()
```

What I get from this is a gaussian-ish shape which is my original data, and a straight horizontal line.

[image]

Also, I'd like to plot my graph using points, instead of having them connected. 
Any input is appreciated!

Comment: You are missing some or your imports. `mean` is the sum of products so needs to be divided by `len(x)`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Here is corrected code:**

```
import pylab as plb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp

x = ar(range(10))
y = ar([0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1])

n = len(x)                          #the number of data
mean = sum(x*y)/n                   #note this correction
sigma = sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n        #note this correction

def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,p0=[1,mean,sigma])

plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')
plt.plot(x,gaus(x,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Fig. 3 - Fit for Time Constant')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.show()
```

**result:**
[image]

Comment: And if you use `plt.plot(x,y,'b+',label='data')` they will be just points.

Comment: Thank you! What are the two corrections you added for by the way?

Comment: This answer does not explain why the correction works better than the original definition.

Comment: To make this work with a different dataset, I added `yn = max(y)`, `y /= yn`, then during plotting, I changed `y` to `y*yn`: `plt.plot(x, y*yn, ...)` .

Comment: @strpeter you would pay attention to the comments in the corrected code. it should be enough explanation.

Comment: @Developer: I guess what you want to do is dividing by `sum(y)` or equally e.g. `mean = np.average(x, weights=y)` which is equal to `5.0`. I ask myself why you divide by `n`  which returns `12.0` - a value that is far from the real value. In a general case you cannot even be sure that this converges to the right values since it would be correct to divide by `sum(y)` which can be far from `n`.

Comment: @EL_DON why does scaling y between 0 and 1 help? It works for me but I dont understand why its necessary

Comment: @HereItIs The fitting routine can internally hit a floating overflow (underflow) if the input data are extremely large (small). Normalizing to the maximum input value usually prevents this.

Comment: @Developer the comments in the code only mention where the fix happens, they do not explain anything at all.

Answer (score 31):

## Explanation

You need good starting values such that the `curve_fit` function converges at "good" values. I can not really say why your fit did not converge (even though the definition of your mean is strange - check below) but I will give you a strategy that works for non-normalized Gaussian-functions like your one.

### Example

The estimated parameters should be close to the final values (use the [weighted arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) - divide by the sum of all values):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

# weighted arithmetic mean (corrected - check the section below)
mean = sum(x * y) / sum(y)
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y * (x - mean)**2) / sum(y))

def Gauss(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a * np.exp(-(x - x0)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(Gauss, x, y, p0=[max(y), mean, sigma])

plt.plot(x, y, 'b+:', label='data')
plt.plot(x, Gauss(x, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Fig. 3 - Fit for Time Constant')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.show()
```

I personally prefer using numpy.

### Comment on the definition of the mean (including Developer's answer)

Since the reviewers did not like my [edit on #Developer's code](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13020088), I will explain for what case I would suggest an improved code. The mean of developer does not correspond to one of the normal definitions of the mean.

Your definition returns:

```
>>> sum(x * y)
125
```

Developer's definition returns:

```
>>> sum(x * y) / len(x)
12.5 #for Python 3.x
```

The weighted arithmetic mean:

```
>>> sum(x * y) / sum(y)
5.0
```

Similarly you can compare the definitions of standard deviation (`sigma`). Compare with the figure of the resulting fit:

[image: Resulting fit]

### Comment for Python 2.x users

In Python 2.x you should additionally use the new division to not run into weird results or convert the the numbers before the division explicitly:

```
from __future__ import division
```

or e.g.

```
sum(x * y) * 1. / sum(y)
```

Comment: I like the "weighted arithmetic mean". It makes the estimation of mean and std more accurate in some cases (for example, if you have a long left tail and short right tail).        However, when I tried to google a theoretical explanation why "weighted arithmetic mean" is better, I found nothing.    this is weird...

Comment: Did you see the link to Wikipedia? - You can also look up the definition of the expectation value - the value, which is most likely to appear again from the existing data.

Answer (score 6):

You get a horizontal straight line because it did not converge.

Better convergence is attained if the first parameter of the fitting (p0) is put as max(y), 5 in the example, instead of 1.

Answer (score 4):

After losing hours trying to find my error, the problem is your formula:

`sigma = sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n`

This previous formula is wrong, the correct formula is the square root of this!;

`sqrt(sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n)`

Hope this helps

Comment: There is still another error: It is not 1/n but 1/sum(y). Check out [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38431524/2062965).

Answer (score 1):

There is another way of performing the fit, which is by using the 'lmfit' package.  It basically uses the cuve_fit but is much better in fitting and offers complex fitting as well.
Detailed step by step instructions are given in the below link.
http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/model.html#model.best_fit

Answer (score 1):

```
sigma = sum(y*(x - mean)**2)
```

should be

```
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y*(x - mean)**2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you do not need to do a first guess. Simply doing

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp

x = ar(range(10))
y = ar([0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1])

n = len(x)                          #the number of data
mean = sum(x*y)/n                   #note this correction
sigma = sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n        #note this correction

def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y)
#popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,p0=[1,mean,sigma])

plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')
plt.plot(x,gaus(x,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Fig. 3 - Fit for Time Constant')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.show()
```

works fine. This is simpler because making a guess is not trivial. I had more complex data and did not manage to do a proper first guess, but simply removing the first guess worked fine :)

P.S.: use numpy.exp() better, says a warning of scipy