# Fitting a Gaussian to a set of x,y data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve

Firstly this is an assignment I've been set so I'm only after pointers, and I am restricted to using the following libraries, NumPy, SciPy and MatPlotLib.

We have been given a txt file which includes x and y data for a resonance experiment and have to fit both a gaussian and lorentzian fit. I'm working on the gaussian fit at the minute and have tried following the code laid out in a previous question as a basis for my own code. ([Gaussian fit for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206332/gaussian-fit-for-python))

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

energy, intensity = numpy.loadtxt('resonance_data.txt', unpack=True)

n = size(energy)
mean = 30.7
sigma = 10
intensity0 = 45
        
def gaus(energy, intensity0, energy0, sigma):
       return intensity0 * exp(-(energy - energy0)**2 / (sigma**2))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaus, energy, intensity, p0=[45, mean, sigma])

plt.plot(energy, intensity, 'o')
plt.xlabel('Energy/eV')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.title('Plot of Intensity against Energy')
plt.plot(energy, gaus(energy, *popt))
plt.show()
```

Which returns the following graph

[image]

If I keep the expressions for mean and sigma, as in the url posted the curve fit is a horizontal line, so I'm guessing the problem lies in the curve fit not converging or something.

Comment: Somehow the pic you links presents itself as a decent fit....

Comment: The general shape is close to what I would expect but the height of the peak is quite far off. I'm aware its' pretty skewed so its not going to fit perfectly, and that's sort of the point of the assignment, but I would still expect better?

Comment: Are you supposed to be fitting a one or a two dimensional gaussian distribution?

Comment: I would use a lorentzian for this data. Think your fit is converged. Increasing the amplitude would probably decrease the fit of the wings.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your data skews heavily to the left, why Gaussian? Not Boltzmann, Log-Normal, or anything else?

Much of these are already implemented in `scipy.stats`. See `scipy.stats.cauchy` for lorentzian and `scipy.stats.normal` gaussian. An example:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
A=ss.norm.rvs(0, 5, size=(100)) #Generate a random variable of 100 elements, with expected mean=0, std=5
ss.norm.fit_loc_scale(A) #fit both the mean and std
(-0.13053732553697531, 5.163322485150271) #your number will vary.
```

And I think you don't need the `intensity0` parameter, it is just going to be `1/sigma/srqt(2*pi)`, because the density function has to sum up to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we've been told to plot both the Gaussian and Lorentzian and then perform statistical tests to show which is best, so that is the reason for the choice. 

I'll take a look at the scipy functions

Cheers.

Comment: @user3507401 you can [have a look to this example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16651955/832621) to see how to test many different distributions using SciPy.