# sklearn.mixture.GMM to fit multiple Gaussian curves into a histogram, an EM algorithm error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, curve-fitting, gaussian

I'm using sklearn.mixture.GMM to fit two Gaussian curves to an array of data and consequently overlay it with data histogram (dat disturbution is mixture of 2 Gaussian curves).

My data is a list of float number and here is the line of code i am using :

```
clf = mixture.GMM(n_components=1, covariance_type='diag')
clf.fit(listOffValues)
```

if i set n_components to 1, I get the following error:

***"(or increasing n_init) or check for degenerate data.")
RuntimeError: EM algorithm was never able to compute a valid likelihood given initial parameters. Try different init parameters (or increasing n_init) or check for degenerate data.***

and if i use  n_components to 2 there error is:

***(self.n_components, X.shape[0]))
ValueError: GMM estimation with 2 components, but got only 1 samples.***

For the first error, I tried changing all init parameters of GMM, but it didn't make any difference.

Tried an array of random numbers and the code is working perfectly fine.
I cant figure out what possibly can be the issue.

Is there an implementation issue I'm overlooking?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly - you would like to fit you data distribution with gaussians and you have only one feature per element. Than you should reshape your vector to be a column vector:

```
listOffValues = np.reshape(listOffValues, (-1, 1))
```

otherwise, if your listOffValues corresponds to some curve that you want to fit it with several gaussians, than you should use [curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). See [Gaussian fit for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206332/gaussian-fit-for-python)