# How can I fit a gaussian curve in python?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I'm given an array and when I plot it I get a gaussian shape with some noise. I want to fit the gaussian. This is what I already have but when I plot this I do not get a fitted gaussian, instead I just get a straight line. I've tried this many different ways and I just can't figure it out.

```
random_sample=norm.rvs(h)

parameters = norm.fit(h)

fitted_pdf = norm.pdf(f, loc = parameters[0], scale = parameters[1])

normal_pdf = norm.pdf(f)

plt.plot(f,fitted_pdf,"green")
plt.plot(f, normal_pdf, "red")
plt.plot(f,h)
plt.show()
```

[image: click for image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gaussian fit for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206332/gaussian-fit-for-python)

Answer (score 33):

You can use `fit` from [`scipy.stats.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(loc=5.0, scale=2.0, size=1000)
mean,std=norm.fit(data)
```

`norm.fit` tries to fit the parameters of a normal distribution based on the data. And indeed in the example above `mean` is approximately 5 and `std` is approximately 2.

In order to plot it, you can do:

```
plt.hist(data, bins=30, density=True)
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
y = norm.pdf(x, mean, std)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The blue boxes are the histogram of your data, and the green line is the Gaussian with the fitted parameters.

Answer (score 24):

There are many ways to fit a gaussian function to a data set. I often use astropy when fitting data, that's why I wanted to add this as additional answer.

I use some data set that should simulate a gaussian with some noise:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy import modeling

m = modeling.models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=10, mean=30, stddev=5)
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 2000)
data = m(x)
data = data + np.sqrt(data) * np.random.random(x.size) - 0.5
data -= data.min()
plt.plot(x, data)
```

[image]

Then fitting it is actually quite simple, you specify a model that you want to fit to the data and a fitter:

```
fitter = modeling.fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
model = modeling.models.Gaussian1D()   # depending on the data you need to give some initial values
fitted_model = fitter(model, x, data)
```

And plotted:

```
plt.plot(x, data)
plt.plot(x, fitted_model(x))
```

[image]

---

However you can also use just Scipy but you have to define the function yourself:

```
from scipy import optimize

def gaussian(x, amplitude, mean, stddev):
    return amplitude * np.exp(-((x - mean) / 4 / stddev)**2)

popt, _ = optimize.curve_fit(gaussian, x, data)
```

This returns the optimal arguments for the fit and you can plot it like this:

```
plt.plot(x, data)
plt.plot(x, gaussian(x, *popt))
```

[image]