# Curve fitting in Python with constraint of zero slope at edges

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am looking to curve fit the following data, such that I get it to fit a trend with the condition of **zero slope at the edges**. The output of polyfit fits that data, but not with zero slopes at the edges.

Here is what I'm looking to output - pardon my Paint job. I need to it to fit like this so I can properly remove this sine/cosine bias of the data that isn't real towards the center.
[image: Example Output]
Here is the data:

```
[0.23353535 0.25586247 0.26661164 0.26410896 0.24963951 0.22670266
 0.19955422 0.17190263 0.1598439  0.17351905 0.18212444 0.18438673
 0.17952432 0.18314894 0.19265689 0.19432385 0.19605163 0.20326011
 0.20890851 0.20590997 0.21856518 0.23771665 0.24530019 0.23940831
 0.22078396 0.23075128 0.2346082  0.22466281 0.24384843 0.26339594
 0.26414153 0.24664183 0.24278978 0.31023648 0.3614195  0.37773436
 0.3505998  0.28893167 0.23965877 0.24063917 0.27922502 0.32716477
 0.36553767 0.42293146 0.50968856 0.5458872  0.52192533 0.45243764
 0.36313155 0.3683921  0.40942553 0.4420537  0.46145585 0.4648034
 0.4523771  0.4272876  0.39404616 0.3570107  0.35060245 0.3860975
 0.3996996  0.44551122 0.46611032 0.45998383 0.4309985  0.38563925
 0.37105605 0.4074444  0.48815584 0.5704579  0.6448988  0.7018853
 0.73397845 0.73739105 0.7122451  0.6618154  0.591451   0.5076601
 0.48578677 0.47347385 0.4791471  0.48306277 0.47025493 0.43479836
 0.44380915 0.45868078 0.5341566  0.57549906 0.55790776 0.56244135
 0.57668275 0.561856   0.67564166 0.7512851  0.76957643 0.7266262
 0.734133   0.7231936  0.6776926  0.60511285 0.51599765 0.5579323
 0.56723005 0.5440337  0.5775593  0.5950776  0.5722321  0.57858473
 0.5652703  0.54723704 0.59561515 0.7071321  0.8169259  0.91443264
 0.9883759  1.0275097  1.0235045  0.9737119  1.029139   1.1354861
 1.1910824  1.1826864  1.1092159  0.9832138  0.9643041  0.92324203
 0.9093703  0.88915515 1.0007693  1.0542978  1.0857164  1.0211861
 0.88474303 0.8458009  0.76522666 0.7478076  0.90081936 1.0690157
 1.1569089  1.1493248  1.0622779  1.0327609  0.9805119  0.9583969
 0.8973544  0.9543319  0.9777171  0.94951093 0.97323567 1.0244237
 1.0569099  1.0951824  1.0771195  1.3078191  1.7212077  2.09409
 2.320331   2.3279085  2.125451   1.7908521  1.4180487  1.0744424
 1.0218129  1.0916439  1.1255138  1.125803   1.1139745  1.2187989
 1.300092   1.3025533  1.2312403  1.221301   1.2535597  1.2298189
 1.1458241  1.1012102  1.0889369  1.1558667  1.3051153  1.4143198
 1.6345526  1.8093723  1.9037704  1.8961821  1.7866236  1.5958548
 1.3865516  1.5308585  1.6140417  1.627337   1.5733193  1.4981418
 1.5048542  1.4935548  1.4798748  1.4131776  1.3792214  1.3728334
 1.3683671  1.3593615  1.2995907  1.2965002  1.366058   1.4795257
 1.5462885  1.61591    1.5968509  1.5222199  1.6210756  1.7074443
 1.8351102  2.3187535  2.6568012  2.7676315  2.6480794  2.3636303
 2.0673316  1.9607923  1.8074365  1.713272   1.5893831  1.4734347
 1.507817   1.5213271  1.6091452  1.7162323  1.7608733  1.7497622
 1.9187828  2.0197518  2.0487514  2.01107    1.9193696  1.7904462
 1.8558109  2.1955926  2.4700975  2.6562278  2.675197   2.6645825
 2.6295316  2.4182043  2.2114453  2.2506614  2.2086055  2.0497518
 1.9557768  1.901191   2.067513   2.1077373  2.0159333  1.8138607
 1.5413624  1.600069   1.7631899  1.9541935  1.9340311  1.805134
 2.0671906  2.2247658  2.2641945  2.3594956  2.2504601  1.9749025
 1.8905054  2.0679731  2.1193469  2.0307171  2.0717037  2.0340347
 1.925536   1.7820351  1.9467943  2.315468   2.4834185  2.3751369
 2.0240622  1.9363666  2.1732547  2.3113241  2.3264208  2.22015
 2.0187428  1.7619076  1.796859   1.8757095  2.0501778  2.44711
 2.6179967  2.508112   2.1694388  1.7242104  1.7671669  1.862043
 1.8392721  1.7120028  1.6650634  1.6319505  1.482931   1.5240219
 1.5815579  1.5691646  1.4766116  1.3731087  1.4666644  1.4061015
 1.3652745  1.425564   1.4006845  1.5000012  1.581379   1.6329607
 1.6444355  1.6098644  1.5300899  1.6876912  1.8968476  2.048039
 2.1006014  2.0271482  1.8300935  1.6986666  1.9628603  2.0521066
 1.9337255  1.6407858  1.2583638  1.2110122  1.2476432  1.2360718
 1.2886397  1.2862154  1.2343681  1.1458222  1.209224   1.2475786
 1.2353342  1.1797879  1.0963987  1.0928186  1.1553882  1.1569618
 1.1932304  1.3002363  1.3386917  1.2973225  1.1816871  1.0557054
 0.9350373  0.896656   0.8565816  0.90168726 0.9897751  1.02342
 1.0232298  1.1199353  1.1466643  1.1081418  1.0377598  1.0348651
 1.0223045  1.0607077  1.0089502  0.885213   1.023178   1.1131796
 1.1331098  1.0779471  0.9626393  0.81472665 0.85455835 0.87542623
 0.87286425 0.89130884 0.9545931  1.0355722  1.0201533  0.93568784
 0.9180018  0.8202782  0.7450139  0.72550577 0.68578506 0.6431666
 0.66193295 0.6386373  0.7060119  0.7650972  0.80093855 0.803342
 0.76590335 0.7151591  0.6946282  0.7136788  0.7714012  0.8022328
 0.79840165 0.8543819  0.8586749  0.8028453  0.7383879  0.73423904
 0.65107304 0.61139977 0.5940311  0.6151931  0.59349155 0.54995483
 0.5837645  0.5891752  0.56406695 0.5638191  0.5762535  0.58305734
 0.5830114  0.57470953 0.5568098  0.52852243 0.49031836 0.45275375
 0.47168964 0.46634504 0.4600581  0.45332378 0.41508177 0.3834329
 0.4137769  0.41392407 0.3824464  0.36310086 0.434278   0.48041886
 0.49433306 0.475708   0.43060693 0.36886734 0.34740242 0.34108457
 0.36160505 0.40907663 0.43613982 0.4394311  0.42070773 0.38575593
 0.3827834  0.4338096  0.46581286 0.45669746 0.40830874 0.3505502
 0.32584783 0.3381971  0.33949164 0.36409503 0.3759155  0.3610108
 0.37174097 0.39990777 0.38925973 0.34376588 0.32478797 0.32705626
 0.3228174  0.30941254 0.28542265 0.2687348  0.25517422 0.26127565
 0.27331188 0.3028561  0.31277937 0.29953563 0.2660389  0.27051866
 0.2913383  0.30363902 0.30684754 0.3011791  0.28737035 0.26648855
 0.26413882 0.25501928 0.23947525 0.21937743 0.19659272 0.18965112
 0.21511254 0.23329383 0.24157354 0.2391297  0.22697571 0.20739041
 0.1855308  0.18856761 0.19565174 0.20542233 0.21473111 0.22244582
 0.22726117 0.22789808 0.22336568 0.21322969 0.20314343 0.2031754
 0.19738965 0.1959791  0.20284075 0.20859875 0.21363212 0.21804498
 0.22160804 0.22381367]
```

This came close, but not exactly it as the edges aren't zero slope: [How do I fit a sine curve to my data with pylab and numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716302/how-do-i-fit-a-sine-curve-to-my-data-with-pylab-and-numpy)
[image]

Is there anything available that will let me do this without having to write up a custom algorithm to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480137/how-can-i-fit-a-gaussian-curve-in-python/44480190](This link) may help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Lorentzian type of peak equation fitted to your data, and for the "x" values I used an index similar to what I see on the Example Output plot in your post. I have also zoomed in on the peak center to better display the sinusoidal shapes you mention. You may be able to subtract the predicted value from this peak equation to condition or pre-process the raw data as you discuss.

```
a =  1.7056067124682076E+02
b =  7.2900803359572393E+01
c =  2.5047064423525464E+02
d =  1.4184767800540945E+01
Offset = -2.4940994412221318E-01

y = a/ (b + pow((x-c)/d, 2.0)) + Offset
```

[image: plot]

[image: zoomed]

Answer (score 1):

Starting from you own example based on a sine fit, I added the constraints such that the derivatives of the model have to be zero at the end points. I did this using `symfit`, a package I wrote to make this kind of thing easier. If you prefer to do this using `scipy` you can adapt the example to that syntax if you want, `symfit` is just a wrapper around their minimizers that adds symbolical manipulations using `sympy`.

```
# Make variables and parameters
x, y = variables('x, y')
a, b, c, d = parameters('a, b, c, d')
# Initial guesses
b.value = 1e-2
c.value = 100

# Create a model object
model = Model({y: a * sin(b * x + c) + d})

# Take the derivative and constrain the end-points to be equal to zero.
dydx = D(model[y], x).doit()
constraints = [Eq(dydx.subs(x, xdata[0]), 0),
               Eq(dydx.subs(x, xdata[-1]), 0)]

# Do the fit!
fit = Fit(model, x=xdata, y=ydata, constraints=constraints)
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)

plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, model(x=xdata, **fit_result.params).y)
plt.show()
```

This prints: (from current symfit [PR#221](https://github.com/tBuLi/symfit/pull/221), which has better reporting of the results.)

```
Parameter Value        Standard Deviation
a         8.790393e-01 1.879788e-02
b         1.229586e-02 3.824249e-04
c         9.896017e+01 1.011472e-01
d         1.001717e+00 2.928506e-02
Status message         Optimization terminated successfully.
Number of iterations   10
Objective              <symfit.core.objectives.LeastSquares object at 0x0000016F670DF080>
Minimizer              <symfit.core.minimizers.SLSQP object at 0x0000016F78057A58>

Goodness of fit qualifiers:
chi_squared            29.72125657199736
objective_value        14.86062828599868
r_squared              0.8695978050586373

Constraints:
--------------------
Question: a*b*cos(c) == 0?
Answer:   1.5904051811454707e-17

Question: a*b*cos(511*b + c) == 0?
Answer:   -6.354261416082215e-17
```

[image]