# Problem fitting gaussian with negative amplitude using astropy.modeling

Tags: python, python-3.x, astropy

I am trying to fit a gaussian to a discrete potential using the astropy.modeling package. Although I assign a negative amplitude to the gaussian, it returns a null gaussian, i.e, with zero amplitude everywhere:

```
plot(c[0], pot_x, label='Discrete potential')
plot(c[0], g(c[0]), label='Gaussian fit') 
legend()
```

[image]

I have the following code lines to perform the fitting:

```
g_init = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=-1., mean=0, stddev=1.)
fit_g = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
g = fit_g(g_init, c[0], pot_x)
```

Where

```
c[0] = array([13.31381488, 13.31944489, 13.32507491, 13.33070493, 13.33633494,
   13.34196496, 13.34759498, 13.35322499, 13.35885501, 13.36448503,
   13.37011504, 13.37574506, 13.38137507, 13.38700509, 13.39263511,
   13.39826512, 13.40389514, 13.40952516, 13.41515517, 13.42078519])

pot_x = array([ -1.72620157,  -3.71811187,  -6.01282809,  -6.98874144,
    -8.36645166, -14.31787771, -23.3688849 , -26.14679496,
   -18.85970983, -10.73888697,  -7.10763373,  -5.81176637,
    -5.44146953,  -5.37165105,  -4.6454408 ,  -2.90307138,
    -1.66250349,  -1.66096343,  -1.8188269 ,  -1.41980552])
```

Does anyone have an ideia what the problem might be?

**Solved**: I just had to assign a mean that is in the range of the domain, like 13.35.

Comment: Which library are you using for the fitting and the `models.Gaussian1D`? Does it need to use this library, or could we fit the data with a different one?

Comment: I'm using the astropy.modeling.models package [link](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/reference_api.html#module-astropy.modeling). Probably there is a different one which performs the same thing, but by know astropy is the only I know.

Comment: Ok, I did the same thing with scipy.optimize.curve_fit and the result was the same: a null gaussian. Maybe a gaussian isn't the best fit for it.

Comment: Gaussian looks correct, I'll do the fitting a bit later

Comment: Problem solved. The mean was out of the range of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not familiar with Astropy, I used scipy. The code below provides the following outpt:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.asarray([13.31381488, 13.31944489, 13.32507491, 13.33070493, 13.33633494,
   13.34196496, 13.34759498, 13.35322499, 13.35885501, 13.36448503,
   13.37011504, 13.37574506, 13.38137507, 13.38700509, 13.39263511,
   13.39826512, 13.40389514, 13.40952516, 13.41515517, 13.42078519])

y = -np.asarray([ -1.72620157,  -3.71811187,  -6.01282809,  -6.98874144,
    -8.36645166, -14.31787771, -23.3688849 , -26.14679496,
   -18.85970983, -10.73888697,  -7.10763373,  -5.81176637,
    -5.44146953,  -5.37165105,  -4.6454408 ,  -2.90307138,
    -1.66250349,  -1.66096343,  -1.8188269 ,  -1.41980552])

mean = sum(x * y) / sum(y)
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y * (x - mean)**2) / sum(y))

def Gauss(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a * np.exp(-(x - x0)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(Gauss, x, y, p0=[max(y), mean, sigma])

plt.plot(x, y, 'b+:', label='data')
plt.plot(x, Gauss(x, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')
plt.legend()
```

[image: Curve fitting]

By simplicity, I reused this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38431524/2062965). I am not entirely certain about the mean and sigma definition, as I am not used to fitting a Gaussian on a 2D dataset. However, it doesn't really matter as it is simply used to define an approximatation used to start the curve_fit algorithm.

Comment: FWIW `astropy.modeling` mostly uses scipy under the covers, so this is effectively the same thing the OP is doing, with the difference (as the OP started out) that the initial estimate for the mean should at least be somewhere in the domain of the data or else the fit will go off in the weeds.